# Inconsistent behaviour of CSS flex items' dimensions when dimensions are relative

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am testing css FLEX for a project. I use my own tags.

I create a page with many flexboxes..

Simply:

I create a container stretching to the limits of viewer window. [RED]

I create a grid container in it but this time it uses height 100%. [PASTELGREEN]

If I give a fixed dimension to grid container's max-height example : 800px; flexboxes in grid container float.

But if I change height to 100%; they do not float anymore. The keep stretching the container until no more flex item left.

HTML :

```
<body>
<pc-pagecontainer>
<pc-colgrid>
<pc-box></pc-box><pc-box2></pc-box2><pc-box></pc-box>
<pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box>
<pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box>
</pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box>
<pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box>
</pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box>
<pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box>
</pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box>
<pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box>
</pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box2></pc-box2><pc-box>
</pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box>
<pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box>
</pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box>
<pc-box></pc-box><pc-box2></pc-box2><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box>
</pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box>
<pc-box></pc-box><pc-box></pc-box><pc-box2></pc-box2>
</pc-colgrid>
</pc-pagecontainer>
</body>
```

Here is CSS

```
pc-pagecontainer {  
display:flex;display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
-webkit-align-items: flex-start;align-items:flex-start;
flex-direction:row;-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;flex-wrap: wrap;
padding=0;
justify-content:center;webkit-justify-content: center;
min-height:100vh;
min-width=100vw;
background-color:#F00;

}


pc-colgrid{
        display:-webkit-flex;display: flex;flex-direction:column;
       -webkit-align-items:stretch;
       align-items: stretch;
       -webkit-justify-content:stretch ;
       justify-content:stretch ; 
       -webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap;
       -webkit-align-content:  center;align-content: center;
        padding=0;background-color:#396;max-height:100vh;width:100%;
        }



pc-box {
    display:-webkit-flex;display: flex;flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-width:100px;min-height:100px; background-color:#099; 
    border:1px; border-style:solid;
    }
    pc-box2 {
    display:-webkit-flex;display: flex;flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-width:50px;min-height:100px; background-color: #F90; 
    border:1px; border-style:solid;
    }
```

And here is how it looks :

[image]

Am I struggling with a bug or just doing something wrong ?
Viewer is Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vh` unit is relative to the viewport. So `max-height: 100vh` works without further guidance, because it simply refers to the height of the viewport.

The `%` unit is relative to the parent container. So `max-height: 100%` resolves to `height: auto` (the height of the content; like in your example), *unless* you define a height on the parent.

For `max-height: 100%` to work, add this to your code:

```
html, body, pc-pagecontainer {
    height: 100%;
}
```

More information:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)
- [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)

Comment: Okay I read and reading that .. "I did not know <body> can have a height and used as a reference to the child elements.. "  Thank you ..

Comment: One more question to make it all clear . Viewer height is referring to the viewer window's size.... So when i tell container 100vh. Container has a reference. So grid container as well.. Unless I change viewer window's size... Does not that count as a reference.. ? Cause I can want body to be 2000 pixels but this container to be 100% of the browser window ...